# Imported Eclipse Android Project into Android Studio, but how do I build it?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, intellij-idea

I imported a very old eclipse android project into android studio (well at the moment i am using intellij idea which is the same thing as android studio), using the following steps:

```
clicked Import Project on the Welcome screen
In the dialog that opens, selected the necessary Eclipse project
selected Import project from external model 
then selected Eclipse
```

Now when I go to 'Run App', I get the following error:

```
Error:(42, 23) java: generics are not supported in -source 1.3
  (use -source 5 or higher to enable generics)
```

I do not think my project is using gradle, maven or another build system. I believe it is using the default Eclipse build system. So what steps can I take to adjust the source level in intellij IDEA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `Project Settings` -> `Project` -> `Project language level`, choose a level equal or greater than 5.0:

[image]

Comment: How can I migrate all this to gradle so I don't have to worry about this anymore?

Comment: The default language level is 8 now, so you don't worry about this. I Think the level 1.3 was set somewhere when you doing the import.